# API загрузка файлов на файлообменник

Tags: php, curl, ftp, fileupload

Пишу API для нескольких файлообменников. У некоторых имеется загрузка по FTP и через сайт. Как лучше реализовать загрузку файлов с последующим получением обратной ссылки на этот файл?
1. Можно загружать по FTP, а потом авторизоваться через curl и искать в аккаунте ссылки на файлы по имени файла. 2. Можно сразу через сайт загружать файл и получать инфу о загруженном файле. Какой вариант лучше или еще какие нибудь?

Comment: делайте как можете, а уже по ходу, чем больше будете понимать в своем проекте, будете модернизировать.

Comment: Я бы выбрал второй. Первый только если 2. не получается.